# How to pass optional parameter to a method in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to pass optional parameters to a method in C++ ?

is there a way like in C# we can use this statement Func(identifier:value) which allow me to pass value to any parameter i want .... for example:

```
   //C# Code
   void func(int a=4,int b,int c)
    {
    int sum=a+b+c;
    Console.Write(sum);
    }
    void Main(){ func(b:5,c:6);}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, default arguments have to go last, so you would write:

```
void func(int b, int c, int a=4)
{
    int sum = a+b+c;
    std::cout << sum;
}

int main() {
    func(5, 6); // b = 5, c = 6, a uses the default of 4
}
```

You cannot provide named parameters all the call site the way you can in C# or Python. There is a [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) to fake support for naming parameters, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but, short answer is that a parameter with a default value cannot precede parameters which don't get defaults. So:

```
void func(int a=4,int b,int c) {} //doesn't work
void func(int b, int c, int a = 4){} //works
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments for more information

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can only do it to the rightmost elements.  So you could write `void func(int a, int b, int c=4)` or `void func(int a, int b=2, int c=4)` or even `void func(int a=1, int b=2, int c=4)`, but not the example you gave.